# Realtime Independent Vector Analysis

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, speech-processing, source-separation

I have been working on an implementation of Real-time (Online) IVA (independent vector analysis). The paper I am referring to is: [Real-Time Independent Vector Analysis for Convolutive Blind Source Separation](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5473086)

I wonder whether anybody from here investigated this paper or realized a successful implementation. I couldn't make it work correctly in Matlab.

Comment: you did not insert the link to your paper into your question! Please do that :)

Comment: Generally, you also did not really ask a precise signal processing question. "I couldn't make it work" is not really a signal processing problem – describe where you're stuck, and that the signal processing problem is that you need help with, precisely, to make progress!

Comment: Hi sir, Precisely the problem is how to have a good performance in real-time, Find the good parameter of this method (size of time frame , rate of updating) . this is the code I wrote https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mwrLuw0UcCykCkNtLXe4WRppXXUwzXJH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ElkoukIlyas: did you profile your code?

Comment: @Hilmar : no I don't